# How to get rid off Error message in plotTangentSpace()? unbenutzte Argumente

Tags: r

I am trying to make a plot with plotTangentSpace, but I always get an error message that says:
“Fehler in plotTangentSpace(allfishadj.shape, groups = info$Cluster) : 
  unbenutzte Argumente (allfishadj.shape, groups = info$Cluster)“
(in English: unused arguments)

Here is the code line: 
PCA1<-plotTangentSpace(allfishadj.shape, groups = info$Cluster, warpgrids = F)

I already tried to take the "new" function of geomorph, but with the same result
"PCA1<-gm.prcomp(allfishadj.shape, groups = info$Cluster, warpgrids = F)"

Answer (score 0):

That error usually arises when the funtion does not accept one argument that you are including in the function call.

It seems that the function `plotTangentSpace` does not use the argument `groups`.
The function is from the package `geomorph`. I found two versions of the package, one accepts the argumentgroups and the other does not.

V3.2.1, with groups parameter :[https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geomorph/versions/3.2.1/topics/plotTangentSpace]

V1.0 does not include groups: [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geomorph/versions/1.0/topics/plotTangentSpace]

Check what version of the package you have installed.

The other functions you mention `gm.prcomp`also does not accept groups as an argument and therefore the same error arises.

Suggestion: Try to have your R in English, it will be easier to share your problems.